# Android How do display array contents to textview?

Tags: android, textview

How do I loop around contents of an array and display line by line on a text view

java code

```
package com.stuff;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.UserDictionary;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ScrumActivity extends Activity 
{
    TextView textout;
    EditText inputBox;
    Button okButton;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Scrumer scrumbler = new Scrumer();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Get elements from XML to use in application
        textout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        inputBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputBox);
        okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        String regularText = "This text is ";
        String clickableText = "clickable";
        sb.append(regularText);
        sb.append(clickableText);
        sb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan(), sb.length()-clickableText.length(), sb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        //tv.setText(sb);




        //setting a listener for the button to be clicked
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                //textout.setText(inputBox.getText().toString());
                scrumer.jumble(inputBox.getText().toString());


                for(String s : scrumbler.getMatchArray())
                    sb.append(s+"\n");

                textout.setText("ok");

                System.out.print(sb.toString());
            }
        });     
    }    
}
```

Heres my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do you want to display all the text at the same time? or replace the text every X seconds?

Comment: @BinyaminSharet all at once. like if i had a string = "hello" I would like to put it into a char array and see each character on a new line

Comment: Damn I got hammered on this question for some reason

Comment: The original question was too vague and didn't show much effort... I see your update, the real question is what are you trying to do with your new links?

Comment: @Sam in the onclick event section I'm trying to get the contents to spit out line-by-line, having each line clickable

Comment: Yes, but what will each line do: launch a new activity, open a detailed dialog, play a song? Is a ListView a better choice? A ListView easily creates a dynamic number of clickable objects on their own line and ListViews are far simpler to interact with. PS I wasn't one of the downvoters...

Comment: @Sam thanks Sam, Im really new to android so I'm not sure how to successfully use the ListView. All my previous tries with listView crash out my application

Comment: Here's decent tutorial on [ListViews](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) to help you out.

Answer (score 4):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String[] arr = {"These","are","some","words"};
for (String s : arr){
  builder.append(s).append(" ");
textview.setText(builder.toString());
```

Will put `These are some words` into your TextView. If you want a line-break after every single string, use `builder.append(s).append("\n");`